# Visual Studio 2010: breakpoint hits on wrong file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

I don't have much hope anyone will be able to answer this, but I'll try anyway:

In Visual Studio 2010, when I click to set a breakpoint in any file, another file opens and the breakpoint gets set to the same line number in that file instead.

To illustrate:

1. I open foo.cs
2. I click to add a breakpoint on line 100
3. VS opens bar.cs and sets a breakpoint on (the wrong) line 100
4. I spew curses at Microsoft

As always, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried: Clean Solution, Delete bin and obj directory, Rebuild all solution?

Comment: By chance, did it happen on identically named files within different projects (unlike you foo/bar example)?

Comment: I never heard of this one before.  The pdb is screwed up somehow.  Could be a build problem, could be because it is Friday the 13th.  I have to pick the latter with the amount of info provided.

Comment: I have the same issue, it even jumps to the wrong file when I try to set the breakpoint! Same problem when I try to step into the files. For me it always seems to happen in *.h files though.

Comment: Exactly the same issue. It is the same file name in a different project. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone!

I have the exact same issue with Visual Studio 2015 and it's very annoying.
In my experience, it only happens when 2 different projects (in the same solution) both contain a file with the same name.

It's related to the different PDB files and the order in which they are loaded. If the debugger can find a file with matching name, it doesn't seems to care whether it's found in the good PDB or not.

Sadly enough, this has been documented for a while on MSDN ([msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6aesyw2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6aesyw2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) and it still is not resolved.

Microsoft's workaround is to write the full file path when adding breakpoints, but I don't find this to be a viable solution as it drastically slows down the debugging process.

Here are other "solutions" I have found:

1. Renaming file names (so they become unique);
2. Deleting .SUO file for the solution seem to work in certain cases (doesn't work for me);
3. Deleting the PDB files for the "wrong" project (hopefully you are not trying to debug both simultaneously);
4. Changing options for the "wrong" project so it doesn't generate/read
   PDB files at runtime.

Hope this helps!